# How to add and check for constraints when sending logs using Cloud Watch Logs SDK

Tags: asp.net, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I successfully sent my application logs which is in JSON format to Cloud Watch Logs using the Cloud Watch Logs SDK but I could not understand how to handle the constraints provided by the end point.

**Question 1:** [Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_PutLogEvents.html) says

> If you call PutLogEvents twice within a narrow time period using the
>   same value for sequenceToken, both calls may be successful, or one may
>   be rejected.

Now what the word "May Be" means, is there no certain outcome?

**Question 2:**

Restriction is 10,000 `inputlogevent` are allowed in one batch, this is not too hard to incorporate code wise but there is size constraint too, only 1 MB can be sent in one batch. Does that mean every time I append `inputlogevent` to `logevent` collection/batch I need to calculate the size of the batch? Does that mean I need to check for both number of `inputlogevent` as well as `size of overall batch` when sending logs? Isn't that too cumbersome?

**Question 3**

What happens if one of my `inputlogevent`'s 100th character reached 1 MB. Then I cannot simply send incomplete last log with just 100 characters, I would have to comepletely take that `inputlogevent` out of the picture and send it as a part of other batch?

**Question 4**

With multiple docker container writing logs, there will be constant change in sequence token, and alot of calls will fail coz sequence token will keep on changing.

**Question 5:**

In offical POC they have not checked any constraint at all. why so?
[PutBatchEvent POC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/dotnet-CloudWatchLogs-AwsCloudWatchSample1-Program.cs.html)

Am I thinking in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my understanding on how to use Cloudwatch log. Hope this helps

Question 1: I believe there is no guarantee due to the nature of distributed systems, your request can land on the same cluster and be rejected or land of different clusters and both of them accept it

Question 2 & Question 3: For me log events should always be small, fast and put pretty rapidly. Most logging frameworks do help you configure ( Batch size for AWS / Number of lines for file logging... ) [Take a look at these frameworks](https://github.com/aws/aws-logging-dotnet)

Question 4: Each of your containers ( Or, any parallel application unit) should use and maintain their own sequenceTokens and each of them will get a separate log stream